# Referencing a specific Google map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

. .

I've created a Google map (V3) that includes multiple markers.  I've come across a need to redefine properties for specific markers.  However, I have not been able to find any way to refer to specific marker objects.

To give you an example of what I'm trying to do, let's say I have a US map onto which I've placed markers on New York, Chicago, and Los Angeles.  Let's say I've defined them as follows:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: lat-long-NY, title: "Yankees"});    // NY
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: lat-long-Chi, title: "White Sox"});  // Chicago
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: lat-long-LA, title: "Angels"});     // LA
```

Now, let's say I want to go back and *reset* the marker titles as follows:

```
google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: lat-long-NY, title: "Mets"});    // NY
google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: lat-long-Chi, title: "Cubs"});    // Chicago
google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: lat-long-LA, title: "Dodgers"}); // LA
```

So, how do I do this (or, for that matter, is it even possible)?  I've tried putting the markers in an array and setting an ID for them, but to no avail.  I've also thought about, but haven't tried, referring to them by their title (that's probably next), but I'm not even sure if this is possible.  I have not been able to find anything like this in Google's documentation.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use better names when you create the markers.

```
var NY_marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: lat-long-NY, title: "Yankees"});    // NY
var Chi_marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: lat-long-Chi, title: "White Sox"});  // Chicago
var LA_marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: lat-long-LA, title: "Angels"});     // LA
```

Then, you just need to do this:

```
NY_marker.setTitle("Mets");
Chi_marker.setTitle("Cubs");
LA_marker.setTitle("Dodgers");
```

More getters and setter for you to manipulate your markers:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker

Comment: Gah!!!  Apparently, I wasn't properly setting my array.  I tried it again with the array, and got it to work!  Thanks for the assist!